# How to find lost product key from a previous windows installation

Tags: windows-activation

Many years ago, my pc originally came - as far as I can recall, with a windows 7 installation. I can't quite recall. This installation was  activated with a product key, as always. This I can tell from the fact that windows ran smoothly, without getting locked down as in an unactivated windows xp box, or without my desktop background going black as in an unactivated windows 7 one.

But some time after, I had to install, or maybe reinstall, windows 7, which I did with a windows 7 installation disk - which, it turned out, was a pirated one.

But as far as I know, microsoft somehow assigned the product key that my PC's manufacturers/builders used to register my system - to my system, and I am allowed to use that key as much times as I want on this pc, unless I change my motherboard. I unfortunately never noted down that key.

But I can see two options for me. One, if somehow the first product key stays logged somewhere in my pc - which doesn't seem possible.

As for the second, it seems like my motherboard/system has got some sort of id number - a trace from my motherboard manufacturer , which microsoft saves and stores in a table in their machine/machines, possibly multiple times, against all the product keys I may use to install windows on my pc - for the first, second, third and the umpteenth time; whenever I do the installations.

So, do microsoft gives everyone access to that table? Or do microsoft's policy allows me to contact them, describe my problem, and obtain their assistance promptly in this issue? Either way, how would I know my system id, against which to look - or ask, for my lost product key?

Comment: If you are looking for activation key or whatever for the Windows OS that is currently activated on the machine you will reinstall or whatever, then look for an application called `ShowKeyPlus` via Google. Scan it with https://www.virustotal.com and [verify it is legit and safe](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/36198bc722aaa3168f9d8acc3cd06da0ca43fc145ab2fb5a6266f57a5ed8f58e/detection) and you will be all set.

Comment: I don't think that's what OP want. He wanted the original product key, not the key he used during reinstall. I would suggest checking the PC to see if there is a recovery partition. The Windows installed through recovery partition is usually pre-activated.

Comment: The Windows 7 license is printed o the COA sticker on the device.

Comment: "Or do Microsoft's policy allows me to contact them, describe my problem, and obtain their assistance promptly in this issue?" - Microsoft doesn't know your product key.  Contacting them would be a waste of your time.

Comment: @Ramhound I want the original product key, as     some user    said.

Comment: @some user    Thanks, can you detail the procedure/scheme you are suggesting....maybe in an answer?

Comment: @TonyMarshle - The original product key is the license key printed on the COA sticker.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.squidworks.net/2015/03/how-to-windows-7-oem-activation/

This worked for me on an OEM Dell Laptop.  If I remember right I used a generic Windows 7 Install that was same type (pro) and when I did not have a key for activation (because windows activates via hardware) this did the trick.  You're "mileage" will vary.

> In windows Vista, 7, server 2008, 2008r2, and server 2012 OEM activation is accomplished by the combination of 3 elements.
>
> The bios of the system must contain what is called a “SLIC” string, all systems made by a major OEM such as Dell, HP will include this. Home built systems will not (unless you modify the bios yourself)
>   A certificate file that matches up against the “SLIC” string that is stored in the BIOS. These certificate files are unique to each OEM so Dell has their own, HP has their own, etc. and are not interchangeable.
>   A Windows product key that tells the system to use OEM activation instead of the traditional Microsoft activation process. These keys are not specific to a particular OEM and are interchangeable.
>   If all 3 are present the system is instantly activated, does not communicate with MS to determine if activation is valid or to activate against a MS server. The activation is already trusted.
>
> When you rebuild a PC component 1 is still present but #2 and # 3 are missing.
>
> Attached in the SLIC.zip file you will find the certificate files used by Major OEM’s such as Dell, HP, Lenovo, as well as product keys that can be used for Windows 7 Professional, and Ultimate.

[SLIC Zip File Download](http://www.squidworks.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/SLIC.zip)

> To use this, for example if you had a Dell.
>
> Open an elevated command prompt, extract the Dell certificate to C:\temp
>
> The certificate is called Dell-Dell-2.0.xrm-ms
>
> So issue the command slmgr –ilc c:\temp\dell-dell-2.0.xrm-ms
>
> Then issue the command slmgr –ipk 2QTV2-3CMPP-FQBYK-XXXXX-XXXXX (For windows 7 Pro)
>
> Wait about 5 seconds and if you look that system is now genuine and activated.